# How do I optimize retrieval of related records in self referencing model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-queryset

I am creating a form from a model. This form contains a category. The category model is a self referencing model. I want to display the categories in a dropdown on the form so they show their parent categories too. ie,

`parentcat3 > parentcat2 > parentcat1 > leafcategory`

the last category is denoted by `leafCategory=True`.

I have overridden my ModelForm to select records only that are leaf (end) categories using;

```
self.fields['primaryCategory'].queryset = Category.objects.exclude(leafCategory=False)
```

The ModelForm dropdown then uses the return value from `__unicode__` in the model which is;

`getFullPathString()`

This walks back up the 'tree' to find the parent categories. This is the part that is slow (there are 10,000 categories)

How can I optimize the retrieval of the parent records?

Here is the code I am using:

### Model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self",related_name='related_category',null=True)
    leafCategory=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.getFullPathString()

    def getParentArray(self):
        """Create an array of parent objects from the current category """
        itemArray=[]

        itemArray.insert(0,self)
        parentCat=self.parent

        while parentCat:
            itemArray.insert(0,parentCat)
            parentCat=parentCat.parent
        return itemArray

    def getFullPathString(self):
        """Get the parent category names, cat 1 > cat 2 etc"""
        returnText=""
        for item in self.getParentArray():
            returnText += item.name
            if not item.isLeaf():
                returnText += " > "
        return returnText
```

### Form

```
class InventoryForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InventoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['primaryCategory'].queryset = Category.objects.exclude(leafCategory=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is incredibly inefficient. It will do a new series of database queries for every single category, and for each category's ancestor.

You need to look into the algorithms that are optimised for storing and retrieving this sort of hierarchical data in a database. [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/) is my favourite of these.

As an aside, it is also inefficient to repeatedly insert elements at the start of a list. Lists are optimised for appending, they are not optimised for inserting. A data structure optimised for adding at both ends is the `deque` in Python's `collections` module - but a better solution would probably be to simply append the elements, then call `reverse()` on the list before returning it.

Comment: +1 for django-mptt, though sometimes modelling a tree via materialized path, as django-treebeard offers it, is also quite useful

Comment: why not caching the path ? in this specific case seems pretty easy and effective

Comment: @Tommaso Thanks. This way suited me best.